# using a queryset to generate options for select widget on IntegerField in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to make a site where users can have multiple avatars and pick the one they want to use when entering a room.  (It will be a dice-rolling app.)  I've been stuck for three days trying to figure out how to pass a queryset into a form to use as the options for a select widget that's on an IntegerField.  Right now, I think I have successfully passed the information into the form, but nothing is rendering in the widget.  (I've even got a print statement in the form to prove to myself that the information has made its way in.)

model.py

```
class EnterSWroom(models.Model):
    room_number = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    passcode = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    default_avatar = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

forms.py

```
class Enter_SW_Room(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EnterSWroom
        widgets = {'default_avatar': forms.Select(choices=[])}
        fields = ('room_number', 'passcode', 'default_avatar')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        imported_list = kwargs.pop('avatar_list')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['default_avatar'].choices = imported_list
        print(self.fields['default_avatar'].choices)  #this is just for debugging; see example below
```

views.py

```
class DockingBay(FormMixin, TemplateView):
    form_class = Enter_SW_Room

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        # get tuples for avatar choices
        # get user first name (if exists), else use username
        if self.request.user.userprofile.user_first_name:
            user_name = self.request.user.userprofile.user_first_name
        else:
            user_name = self.request.user.username
        # instantiate avatars list, start with user name
        my_avatars = Avatar.objects.filter(user_id=self.request.user.id)
        my_avatars_choices = [(0, user_name)]
        for avatar in my_avatars:
            if avatar.deleted != 1:
                my_avatars_choices.append((avatar.id, avatar.avatar_name))
        kwargs['avatar_list'] = my_avatars_choices
        return kwargs

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs = self.get_form_kwargs()
        # cut for brevity
        form = Enter_SW_Room(**kwargs)
        args = {'form': form, # other args that were cut from this example}

        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
...
```

Example of a print: `[(0, 'Eric')]`
But, even though the print suggests that I've successfully gotten the queryset to the form, the selection widget displays nothing.

Thanks in advance!

edit to add snippet of html template:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        <col width="240">
        <col width="120">
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Room ID:</strong>
            <br>This will be a number.</td>
            <td>{{form.room_number}} <br>
                <strong>{{ form.room_number.errors }}</strong>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Passcode:</strong>
            <br>If the room is open, or you've been in it before, leave this  blank.</td>
            <td>{{form.passcode}} <br>
                <strong>{{ form.passcode.errors }}</strong>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Avatar:</strong>
            <br>Select your avatar.</td>
            <td>{{form.default_avatar}} <br>
                <strong>{{ form.default_avatar.errors }}</strong>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="submit">Enter Room</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you also include the template in your code above?

Comment: Sure.  Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I'm an idiot.  Forgot to define the field in the form.

added:

```
default_avatar = forms.ChoiceField()
```

to the form.  Now it works.  Arrrrrgh!

Answer (score 0):

You can directly set your choice fields in your form init like this and filter by the current user.

```
class Enter_SW_Room(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Enter_SW_Room, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['default_avatar'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
           queryset=Avatar.objects.filter(user=user).exclude(deleted=1)
    )

class Meta:
    model = EnterSWroom
    ......
```

When initialising the form, pass the user.

```
form = Enter_SW_Room(self.request.user)
```

Comment: Good news, bad news.  The good news is that at least the choice field now displays something.  The bad news is that it is displaying avatar objects (which the integerfield that is the model can't handle the selection).  Also, this method will miss the user name as the first option.  (All users will have a user name; not all users will have avatars, so the first option needs to be tied to the user; see if/else in get_form_kwargs.